# Uncaught Exception java.lang.StackOverflowError. See log file for details. in JMeter3.2 version

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, performance, jmeter-plugins, exception

```
2017-11-20 11:18:29,079 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:1038) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:406) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptLoader.loadClass(ScriptLoader.java:55) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2068) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context$ContextCodeInstaller$1.run(Context.java:209) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context$ContextCodeInstaller$1.run(Context.java:204) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context$ContextCodeInstaller.initialize(Context.java:204) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.CompilationPhase$InstallPhase.transform(CompilationPhase.java:508) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.CompilationPhase.apply(CompilationPhase.java:624) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:655) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.compile(Context.java:1317) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.compileScript(Context.java:1251) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.compileScript(Context.java:627) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.compileImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:535) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.compileImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:524) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:402) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:155) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.IfController$NashornJsEngine.evaluate(IfController.java:124) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.IfController.evaluateCondition(IfController.java:185) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.IfController.next(IfController.java:239) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.nextIsAController(GenericController.java:219) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:173) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
```

Hi
while running Jmeter i am getting Stackoverflow Exception by occurring this my testplan is not getting proper output i just reduces the thread group user but no use. it is occurring  when one by one   thread completes on that time ts is   showing like this.please tell me how to fix this issue.

```
summary +    221 in 00:00:30 =    7.4/s Avg:   113 Min:     6 Max:  1533 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 10 Started: 110 Finished: 100
summary =   9028 in 00:21:39 =    7.0/s Avg:   368 Min:     5 Max: 34202 Err:     0 (0.00%)
summary +    239 in 00:00:30 =    8.0/s Avg:    99 Min:     5 Max:  1518 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 10 Started: 110 Finished: 100
summary =   9267 in 00:22:09 =    7.0/s Avg:   361 Min:     5 Max: 34202 Err:     0 (0.00%)
summary +    220 in 00:00:30 =    7.3/s Avg:   110 Min:     6 Max:  2010 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 10 Started: 110 Finished: 100
summary =   9487 in 00:22:39 =    7.0/s Avg:   355 Min:     5 Max: 34202 Err:     0 (0.00%)
summary +    224 in 00:00:30 =    7.4/s Avg:    82 Min:     5 Max:   550 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 10 Started: 110 Finished: 100
summary =   9711 in 00:23:09 =    7.0/s Avg:   349 Min:     5 Max: 34202 Err:     0 (0.00%)
Uncaught Exception java.lang.StackOverflowError. See log file for details.
summary +    173 in 00:00:30 =    5.8/s Avg:   132 Min:     6 Max:  1507 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 9 Started: 110 Finished: 101
summary =   9884 in 00:23:39 =    7.0/s Avg:   345 Min:     5 Max: 34202 Err:     0 (0.00%)
summary +    204 in 00:00:30 =    6.9/s Avg:   108 Min:     7 Max:  1389 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 9 Started: 110 Finished: 101
summary =  10088 in 00:24:09 =    7.0/s Avg:   340 Min:     5 Max: 34202 Err:     0 (0.00%)
summary +    204 in 00:00:30 =    6.8/s Avg:   120 Min:     6 Max:  2512 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 9 Started: 110 Finished: 101
summary =  10292 in 00:24:39 =    7.0/s Avg:   336 Min:     5 Max: 34202 Err:     0 (0.00%)
summary +    186 in 00:00:30 =    6.2/s Avg:   142 Min:     6 Max:  4576 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 9 Started: 110 Finished: 101
summary =  10478 in 00:25:09 =    6.9/s Avg:   332 Min:     5 Max: 34202 Err:     0 (0.00%)
summary +    179 in 00:00:30 =    6.0/s Avg:   265 Min:     5 Max: 26738 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 9 Started: 110 Finished: 101
summary =  10657 in 00:25:39 =    6.9/s Avg:   331 Min:     5 Max: 34202 Err:     0 (0.00%)
summary +    187 in 00:00:30 =    6.2/s Avg:    99 Min:     5 Max:  1404 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 9 Started: 110 Finished: 101
summary =  10844 in 00:26:09 =    6.9/s Avg:   327 Min:     5 Max: 34202 Err:     0 (0.00%)
summary +    166 in 00:00:30 =    5.5/s Avg:   435 Min:     6 Max: 57858 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 7 Started: 110 Finished: 103
summary =  11010 in 00:26:39 =    6.9/s Avg:   329 Min:     5 Max: 57858 Err:     0 (0.00%)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller)'s condition, most likely you have an [infinite loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop) or something like that there.

If this is not the case and you're totally sure in your condition logic try switching to [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) instead of JavaScript which is the default language of the If Controller, [Groovy is the most performing scripting language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) supported in JMeter and [it is recommended to use it for any form of scripting starting with JMeter 3.1](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)